# Is "does" ever required in the following sentence?

Tags: word-usage

I have the following sentence.

> Why auto sync consumes a lot of Internet data?

Will it be better/ accurate, if I write it as

> Why does auto sync consume a lot of Internet data?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it would be much better. Your first sentence is wrong from a grammatical standpoint - forming questions in Simple Present does require you to use *do/does* and inversion, with few exceptions (primarily *to be* and modal verbs).

Answer (score 1):

As a *standalone* sentence, where a question is introduced and asked, the second sentence is better—and the first is unidiomatic. In that situation, you should use *do* or *does*.

However, in *some* contexts, the reverse could be the case:

> "I'm asking why autosync consumes a lot of internet data."
>   "Why autosync consumes a lot of internet data?"
>   "Yes, that's what I said."

Note that in the first line of dialogue, although a question is being asked, it's constructed in the form of a statement. In that case, the use of *does* would be inappropriate. Also in the dialogue, the statement is repeated without the *does*, and it also makes sense because of its reference—it's not an *original* question, but a repetition of what went before.